# matlab java class gives nullpointer exception

Tags: java, matlab

i'm trying use a java class in matlab and i get a nullpointer exception.

```
import com.oanda.fxtrade.api.*;

public class TestLogin {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FXClient fxclient = null;

    fxclient = API.createFXGame();

    System.out.print("Logging in as \"" + "\"...");
    fxclient.setWithRateThread(true);
    try {
        fxclient.login("user", "password", "RateTicker Test");
    } catch (SessionException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (InvalidUserException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (InvalidPasswordException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (MultiFactorAuthenticationException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.out.print("login complete. Registering listeners...");

    fxclient.logout();
}
```

if i run this class by itself it runs just fine, it logs in, gives me the message and logs out.

in matlab, i create an instance with

`obj = TestLogin` than

```
obj.main('')
```

and i get:

```
    >> obj.main('')
API proxy version          : null
API implementation jar     : http://dynamic-api.oanda.com/oanda_fxtrade_implementation.jar
Logging in as ""...Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oanda.fxtrade.api.implementation.FXClient.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.oanda.fxtrade.api.implementation.FXClient.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.oanda.fxtrade.api.implementation.FXClient.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.oanda.fxtrade.api.implementation.FXClient.login(Unknown Source)
    at TestLogin.main(TestLogin.java:32)
```

for the test i've hard coded the user and password. the error comes from the fxclient.login line. if there is a null pointer, i guess it doesn't know where the fxclient is?("FXClient" is an interface)

what is the object that needs to be instantiated?

Comment: Have you tested it with the java version matlab is using? You can see the version typing in `ver`. It might be that the library you are using is incompatible to that java version.

Comment: yes, the version match. it looks like there is something i don't understand about how to reference a java object from matlab. like if the "obj = TestLogin" command creates a generic object that cannot be referenced by its name.

Comment: Your way of calling the class seems to be correct, if you take a look at the error stack you see that it called the `login` function and it got an error somewhere in that function.